# Can I safely change the APP_SECRET variable in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, security, docker

Working with docker I was thinking about the possibility of generating a random hash for the APP_SECRET environment variable every time the container is upgraded (since I am not using files on volumes to store the environment variables).

That way the configuration of a Symfony application would be easier since one can omit the APP_SECRET hash on the docker host. Also this could be seen as more secure since people tend to skip or forget to configure secret variables during production deployment.

- What could be possible outcomes or side effects of changing the APP_SECRET variable while the application is running?
- What could be possible outcomes or side effects of changing the APP_SECRET variable while the application is being upgraded?